# Pass both querys with Json

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I am passing the company information with Json, and i want also pass the areas with the same method, but something is not well, can anyone help me?

```
    if($_GET['method']=="get_all_companies"){
    $query = "SELECT company.id as c_id, company.c_name as c_name, company.c_desc as c_desc,company.c_address as c_address FROM company";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result){
        $query_areas = "SELECT company.id as c_id, bussiness_area.* FROM company
                        LEFT JOIN company_area
                        ON company_area.id_company = company.id
                        LEFT JOIN bussiness_area
                        ON bussiness_area.id = company_area.id_area
                        WHERE company_id = c_id";
        $result_areas = mysql_query($query_areas);


        $return_arr = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $areas_arr =  array();
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result_areas, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $row_array['c_id'] = $row['c_id'];
            $row_array['c_name'] = $row['c_name'];
            $row_array['c_desc'] = $row['c_desc'];
            $row_array['c_address'] = $row['c_address'];
            $row_array['bu_title'] = $row2['bu_title'];

            array_push($return_arr,$areas_arr,$row_array);
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($return_arr, $areas_arr);
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'true'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first `json_encode()` the `$areas_arr` variable is not necessary.

`json_encode($return_arr);`